# Filter array of strings, keeping only ones starting with vowels

Tags: javascript, arrays, refactoring, startswith

I realise I've massively overengineered this, but as I'm just starting out with JS, I can't think of how to condense this into something not entirely ridiculous. I know I'm probably going to kick myself here, but can someone refactor this for me?

The aim was to create a new array from a provided one, one that only contained strings starting with vowels. It also needed to be case insensitive.

```
let results = []

for (let i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
  if ((strings[i].startsWith('a')) || (strings[i].startsWith('A')) || (strings[i].startsWith('e')) || (strings[i].startsWith('E')) || (strings[i].startsWith('i')) || (strings[i].startsWith('I')) || (strings[i].startsWith('o')) || (strings[i].startsWith('O')) || (strings[i].startsWith('u')) || (strings[i].startsWith('U'))) {
    results.push(strings[i])
  }
}

return results
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for that:

```js
console.log([
  'Foo',
  'Bar',
  'Abc',
  'Lorem',
  'Ipsum'
].filter(str => /^[aeiou]/i.test(str)));
```

[`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns a new array with all the elements that pass (return a truthy value) the predicate.

[`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) returns `true` if the RegExp finds a match on the string you pass in.

Then, `/^[aeiou]/i` means:

- `^` matches the start of the string.
- `[aeiou]` matches any of the characters inside the square brackets, a single time.
- `i` is a case-insensitive modifier.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
let rex = /^[aeiou]/i;
let results = strings.filter(str => rex.test(str));
```

`/^[aeiou]/i` says "At the beginning of the string (`^`), match a, e, i, o, or u, case-insensitive (the `i` flag)."

Live Example:

```js
let strings = [
  "I'll match",
  "But I won't",
  "And I will",
  "This is another one that won't",
  "Useful match here"
];
let rex = /^[aeiou]/i;
let results = strings.filter(str => rex.test(str));

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are great, but please consider this approach shown below.
If you are new to JS, it will certainly help you understand cornerstones of JS like its array methods.

- The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
var new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue, index, array {
      // Return element for new_array
    }, thisArg)
```

Try using a REPL website like https://repl.it/ in order to see what these methods do...

The following is my proposed answer...

```js
function onlyVowels(array) {
// For every element (word) in array we will...
  return array.map((element) => {
    //  ...convert the word to an array with only characters...
    return (element.split('').map((char) => {
      // ...and map will only return those matching the regex expression
      // (a || e || i || o || u)
      // parameter /i makes it case insensitive
      // parameter /g makes it global so it does not return after 
      // finding first match or "only one"
      return char.match(/[aeiou]/ig)
    // After getting an array with only the vowels the join function
    // converts it to a string, thus returning the desired value
    })).join('')
  })
};

function test() {
  var input = ['average', 'exceptional', 'amazing'];
  var expected = ['aeae', 'eeioa', 'aai']
  var actual = onlyVowels(input)

  console.log(expected);
  console.log(actual);
};

test()
```

Comment: Could you explain your code? You say this will force you to understand, but comments would be better.